# How to disable HTML elements if <option> is set to false?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this form:

```
 <form id="ConfigurazioneForm" method="post">
     <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <label for="abilitato" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Abilita</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select class="form-control" id="abilitato" required>
                        <option value="true">true</option>
                        <option value="false">false</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <label for="mostranome" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Mostra il nome: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select class="form-control" id="mostranome" required>
                        <option value="true">true</option>
                        <option value="false">false</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            </div>
       </form>
```

How do I disable select "mostranome" whenever select "abilitato" is set to false?
I tried in JQuery something like:

```
     $(document).ready(function (){
      if($("#abilitato").val()===false){
      $("#mostranome").prop('disabled',true);
      }
     })
```

But it doesn't get triggered, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#abilitato").val()` gives string not boolean value 'true / false'. So why your compare fail.

Compare with `""` as a string and it's work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#abilitato").val() === "false") {
    $("#mostranome").prop('disabled', true);
  }
  $("#abilitato").change(function() {
    if ($("#abilitato").val() === "true") {
      $("#mostranome").prop('disabled', false);
    } else
      $("#mostranome").prop('disabled', true);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ConfigurazioneForm" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <label for="abilitato" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Abilita</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select class="form-control" id="abilitato" required>
        <option value="false">false</option>
        <option value="true">true</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <label for="mostranome" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Mostra il nome: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select class="form-control" id="mostranome" required>
        <option value="true">true</option>
        <option value="false">false</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way you can do it:

```js
const abilitato = document.getElementById("abilitato");
const mostranome = document.getElementById("mostranome");

abilitato.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  mostranome.disabled = e.target.value === "false";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <form id="ConfigurazioneForm" method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
          <label for="abilitato" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Abilita</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control" id="abilitato" required>
              <option value="true">true</option>
              <option value="false">false</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
          <label for="mostranome" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
            >Mostra il nome:
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select class="form-control" id="mostranome" required>
              <option value="true">true</option>
              <option value="false">false</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```